# How to restart an ec2 server when CloudWatch Synthetics Canary fails?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a site I'm working on, and one of the pages retrieves data from another server, let's call it server B.

Occasionally server B fails to return data, and the main site will give a 500 error.

I want to restart server B when that happens, and I was thinking I could use CW synthetics to do that. I've created a CW alarm to trigger, but I don't have a direct way to restart an ec2 server, since it's not associated directly with one.

I've thought of calling a lambda that will restart the server, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler configuration/solution I can use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can creat an Event Bridge rule for failed canary run by selecting `Synthetics Canary TestRun Failure` from `AWS events` then in `Event pattern -> AWS service` select `Cloudwatch Synthetics`and in `Event type` select `Synthetics Canary TestRun Failure`. From the `Target` select `AWS service -> Select a target` select `EC2 Rebootinstances API call` and give the instance id.

UPDATED:
You can use `custom patterns` and pass your json which can match the failure pattern.
In your case I would use something like,

```
{
  "source": ["aws.synthetics"],
  "detail-type": ["Synthetics Canary TestRun Failure"],
  "region": ["us-east-1"],
  "detail": {
  "account-id": ["123456789012"],
  "canary-id": ["EXAMPLE-dc5a-4f5f-96d1-989b75a94226"],
  "canary-name": ["events-bb-1"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming the default setup will run on any failed Canary test run. Do you know how (or have resources) to configure the EventBridge rule to only listen to a specific Canary test?

Comment: @edank, hiii I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Create an Event Bridge rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule.html) for a [failed canary run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitoring-events-eventbridge.html), that triggers a Lambda function. Have the Lambda function restart the EC2 server via the AWS API/SDK.